# gRPC method naming convention for getting EntitesByIds e.g. StudentsById

Tags: grpc

I was not able to get clarity on the naming convention to follow on google protobuf naming convention documentation. Hence thought to reach out to community to know what should be the method, request & response naming

If i have something that fetches list of student using studentIds, should i name my method

`rpc StudentByIdList(StudentByIdListRequest) returns (StudentByIdResponse)`

or

`rpc ListStudent(StudentIdsRequest) returns (StudentResponse)`

or something else

The 2nd one doesn't seem right because in case i have more than 1 method which fetches students by name starting with and student ids.

I went through the google protobuf naming convention documentation and i did find that preposition is not allowed, so By in the method name is wrong, but how do we represent in method that i want to find Student List of Student Id's

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a documented convention.

The [style guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style) is brief.

If I were implementing your solution, I would 'encode' the difference between the 2+ methods in the request message:

```protobuf
rpc ListStudents(ListStudentsRequest) returns (ListStudentsResponse)
```

`ListStudentsRequest` would include a `oneof` (`id`,`name`) or, more commonly and more extensibly a `filter` field in which constraints could be specified (as a string). This mechanism permits the inclusion of e.g. paging too.

Google has a [Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) repo that documents its services that support gRPC.

You can review the protos files in the [`google`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google) subdirectory to see how Google solves this problem.

The [`proto`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/storage/v2/storage.proto) for Google Cloud Storage includes `List` methods for the various resources in the service.

For [`ListBucketsRequest`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/d7687dcb41b2f99c06dc3e99e35cabc6814ceee6/google/storage/v2/storage.proto#L505) you can see a `prefix` field that's used to filter the results.